Einstein's notion of "covariant"
In his The Meaning of Relativity, pg. $11-12$, Einstein explains the notion of "covariant" along the following lines: 
Consider a point $\mathbf x$ on a straight line $\mathbf x -\mathbf A=\lambda\mathbf B$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Without a loss of generality we can assume that $\mathbf B^T\mathbf B =1$. Now, consider an orthogonal linear transformation (OLT) from the $K_{\mathbf x}$ frame to $K'_{\mathbf x}$ defined by:
$$\mathbf x'=\mathbf a +b\mathbf x$$
where $b=[b_{\mu\nu}]$ is the transformation matrix satisfying $b^Tb=I$. Then the straight line in our transformed frame becomes $\mathbf{x'-A'=}\lambda\mathbf B'$ with $\mathbf A'=b^T\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B'=b^T\mathbf B$.  It therefore implies that straight lines have an underlying property which is independent of the system of coordinates. Formally, this depends upon the fact that the (vector) quantity $\vec q :=(\mathbf x -\mathbf A)-\lambda\mathbf B$ is transformed as components of an interval, $\Delta\mathbf x$. If $\vec q=\vec 0$ for one system of Cartesian coordinates, then $\vec {q'}=\vec 0$ for all systems. Thus we can say that the equation of a straight line is "covariant" with respect to OLT's. 

What I think of the assumption $\mathbf B^T\mathbf B =1$ is that here Einstein is referring to set of homothetic transformations centered at the point $\mathbf A,$ that an OLT maps a homothety centered at $\mathbf A$ to one centered at $\mathbf A'$, preserving their scaling factor $\lambda.$ So, straight lines are mapped to straight lines by an OLT, the points on which are therefore called "covariant" vectors. Is my interpretation correct?
 Edit 
After further reading I find that he is talking about the covariance of laws of physics expressed as equations: a law $F=0$ where $F$ may be a vector or scalar or tensor expression in general, if this law preserves its nature under a transformation, that is if it is transformed to $F'=0$ under the said transformation where $F'$ has similar mathematical form as $F$, then the law is said to be covariant with respect to that transformation.
